# Generate random Hermitian matrices

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, random

I want to generate random Hermitian matrices. For now, random Hermitian matrices with size 2 are obvious to construct. But elegant methods for higher dimension would be nice! Are there methods besides just randomly generating the upper triangular entires and then conjugating each entries to fill in the lower half? Thanks!!

Comment: You can adapt the solution in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11081) to your case; just make sure the random eigenvalues are real.

Comment: Alternatively, generate a random matrix $A$ and take $\frac12(A+A^\dagger)$.

Comment: Very helpful thank you guys!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
a = Table[
  Which[x == y, RandomReal[], x < y, RandomComplex[], x > y, 0],
  {x, 5}, {y, 5}]; 

b = Table[
  If[x <= y, a[[x, y]], Conjugate[a[[y, x]] ]], 
  {x, 5}, {y, 5}];

HermitianMatrixQ[b]
```

(* True *)

Or the simplest (given by Rahul):

```
1/2 ((a = Table[RandomComplex[], {5}, {5}]) + ConjugateTranspose[a]);

HermitianMatrixQ[%]
```

(* True *)